# Trying to add a CData element to a XMLDocument is not working, why?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, cdata

I've created a XMLDocument and I'm trying to add a CData-Section to it.

```
e = doc.CreateElement("PSContent", NS);
ps.AppendChild(e);
XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection(next.getContent());
e.AppendChild(cdata);
```

But the end result is always:

```
<PSContent>Testcontent</PSContent>
```

As you can see, it is missing the CDATA-Tag. It should look like this:

```
<PSContent><![CDATA[Testcontent]]></PSContent>
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: [Write a title that summarizes the specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1):

You have to append cdata to **e** before appending **e** to **ps**.

Your code have to look like this one:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var psContent= doc.CreateElement("PSContent", "yournamespace");
XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection("yourtext");
psContent.AppendChild(cdata);
doc.AppendChild(psContent);
```

Hope this help

Comment: This creates the exact same result